# If the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges, must $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (g(k+1)-g(k))a_{g(k)}$ also diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of strictly positive real numbers (i.e. $a_k\ge a_{k+1}>0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$), and let $g\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a strictly increasing function with $g(1)=1$. A problem in a first year exercise sheet asked to show that the following inequalities hold, which is not difficult.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(g(k+1)-g(k))a_{g(k+1)}\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty(g(k+1)-g(k))a_{g(k)}.$$
Label the lower, upper bounds $l_k=(g(k+1)-g(k))a_{g(k+1)}$ and $u_k=(g(k+1)-g(k))a_{g(k)}$, respectively.

With a bit of thought, and a sketch, there is not much to show for the original problem. Note that $g$ gives us a subsequence of $(a_n)$, and in the series on the LHS and RHS we are forced to repeat terms $g(k+1)-g(k)$-times; in $\sum_k l_k$ we repeat the 'next' (and lesser) term, while in $\sum_k u_k$ we repeat the 'previous' (and greater) term. For example, if $a_n=1/n$ for all $n$, and $g(n)=2n-1$ then we are showing:
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots\le\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\le\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots.$$

---

My question is

> Can we force $\sum_k l_k$ or $\sum_k a_k$ to converge even if $\sum_k u_k$ diverges?

I tried to think up some examples, by cleverly choosing $g$ (e.g. so that $g$ increases sufficiently slowly), but could not find anything, and suspect that the answer is 'no'. Informally speaking, I am thinking that if $\sum_k u_k$ diverges then the 'divergence' happens at the limit point somehow.

---

An equivalent formulation is to consider $l_k$, $a_k$ and $u_k$ as decreasing step functions $$l,a,u\colon [1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$$ 
with a 'step' at most on every integer, with the appropriate conditions on the relationship between their values. If $u\ge a\ge l$ with infinitely many $n$ such that $u(n)=a(n)=l(n)$, then

> Is it true that
>   $$\int u=\infty\implies \int a=\infty,\quad\text{and}\quad \int a=\infty\implies \int l=\infty\;?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Try $g(k)=k!$ and $a_n=\frac1{(k+2)!}$ for every $k!\leqslant n<(k+1)!$ and every $k\geqslant1$, then $\ell_k=\frac1{(k+3)!}((k+1)!-k!)\sim\frac1{k^2}$ and $u_k=\frac1{(k+2)!}((k+1)!-k!)\sim\frac1k$ hence $\sum\limits_k\ell_k$ converges and $\sum\limits_ku_k$ diverges.

Comment: Any monotonic bounded sequence is convergent so the given sum is always convergent.

Comment: @Babyelephant the series may not converge, e.g. $a_n=1/n$

Comment: @Did So you can, that is surprising. Thanks for the example!